# Simple encryption software for the Mac

Tags: security, encryption

I am looking for an application which would allow me to encrypt either a file or a folder. Something like right click on a file/folder, select Encrypt, give it a password and ready.

Of course, it should also be able to afterwards decrypt the said file/folder.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Espionage](http://www.taoeffect.com/espionage/) is also a paid app, but should be 'better' then Knox.

Comment: Could you explain why it 'should be better' than Knox?

Comment: Iam also curious about that

Comment: Espionage seems interesting, by glancing quickly on their website, seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks! Will give it a shot.

Comment: @tomaszsobczak and @Pauk: AFAIK Knox is like the build in described by "Loïc Wolff", and the images/vaults can be opened without having Knox installed - even the 256-bit. With Espionage you get a better security, and it is AFAIK only possible to open the encrypted (file/folder/app) with Espionage.

Answer (score 17):

You can do it with a `.dmg`.

- Open `Disk utility`
- Select `New Image` or `File` > `New` > `Blank disk image`
- Choose the name, where to put it, the size (it will be pre-allocated)
- Choose an encryption
- Leave the other settings by default
- Choose a password

Now, all you have to do when you want to access that folder, is open the `.dmg` file.

And it's free.

I found an app that took care of all of that in 2-3 easy steps but can't seem to find it again. You might have more luck.

Comment: I know about the encrypted .dmg, I don't want that as I have only a couple of files/folders that need encryption and they are already scattered in different places in my filesystem.

Comment: @StelianIancu You should create DMGs for them (or one big DMG for all of them), copy the folders into the DMG, and replace the original folders with aliases or symlinks. As a bonus, OS X will automatically mount the DMG is it's closed and you try to open one of the aliases. It's a much better solution than third party software, really.

Answer (score 4):

You can also have a look at the [*Mac GNU Privacy Guard*](http://macgpg.sourceforge.net/), which brings [GnuPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnupg) to Mac OS X, together with the *GPGFileTool*.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). Whilst it's not a file/folder encryption solution, it creates encrypted volumes from files like the .dmg route, but it's cross platform (if you choose an appropriate file system on the encrypted volume)

Answer (score 1):

[Knox](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/Knox) is paid app but i can really recommend it

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning it's built on FileVault which is part of OS X. Knox adds things like ease of use and scheduling of volumes for backup (to say your Dropbox account).

Comment: Knox seems to do the same as encrypted .dmgs, they even say you can open the vaults without even having it installed.

Answer (score -1):

I usually recommend Espionage to my clients :)

It's awesome and easy to use.

[image]

http://www.taoeffect.com/espionage/

Comment: This application was already recommended.... I see no point in providing the same answer...